# how to search and filter 20k items in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint-2013

I have a lists containing 20k items.I want it to display it in a page and that page also contains filters just like in ecommerce site.I tried to retrieve the whole items at the beginning using rest api and stored it in a json and then filter was appiled to that json.I displayed that JSON using jquery datatable and based on filter box check I redrew the datatable.But this approach is not good as it is taking a huge page load time for me. Please suggest me another solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle 20k items using pagination,that is on each page showed only 30 items.
I was able to implement custom pagination using knockout.js 
I referred this url : http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-how-to-implement.html
Then I created filter and was able to repopulate the the table